# Htaccess force to use https

Tags: .htaccess, slim

Im using slim framework for design an api rest.

The structure of my project is:

```
root
--something1
--something2
--api
 --.htaccess
```

And my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How can i do for that every uri like:

```
http://myserver.com/api/.....
```

go to:

```
https//myserver.com/api/.....
```

But its possible that my domain will be a var??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule should redirect you to HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are you meant to replace the whole `.htaccess` with these two lines @marcel-dumont ?

Comment: No, these 2 lines give the necessary behaviour. but the other rules are still valid. I would put these 2 lines directly below "RewriteEngine On"